# monacaでons-toolbarが画面外に消えてしまう。

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

iosで発生する問題となります。
monaca（onsenui)でテキストエリアなどにフォーカスした場合にキーボードが起動しますが、
キーボードが起動した状態で画面をスクロールするとons-toolbarが画面外に移動してしまいます。

こちら回避方法あるでしょうか。